# MacBook Pro doesn't charge reliably, when being powered by USB-C monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, display, battery, sleep-wake, charging

I have a Lenovo ThinkVision p27h-20, which is a USB-C display, that can provide power and process video-/audio-signals all on the same cable.

When I plug in the monitor, the MacBook almost always notices the charging-cable being plugged in, and `system_profiler SPPowerDataType` shows

```
    AC Charger Information:

      Connected: Yes
      Wattage (W): 65
      Charging: Yes
```

So the charging wattage should be sufficient. However, when the MacBook goes to sleep after being idle for some time, the charging just stops, and `system_profiler SPPowerDataType` shows

```
    AC Charger Information:

      Connected: Yes
      Wattage (W): 65
      Charging: No
```

Sometimes it also doesn't charge, when I wake the MacBook up and re-plug the USB-C cable. I effectively run `watch -n 5 system_profiler SPPowerDataType` and check the charging state multiple times every hour, which is not ideal.

I tested the charging with an Arch Linux-Laptop and everything worked as expected.

How can I fix this issue? Is it even fixable? If not, is there something else I can do, other than buying a new monitor?